# partial derivatives inside volume integrals using spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, spherical-coordinates

I have to evaluate an integral of this form
$$\int\int\int \nabla^2f(r, \theta, \phi)r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$$
where $\nabla^2$ which has partial derivatives, is in spherical coordinates.

Would the $\nabla^2$ operate on the $f(r, \theta, \phi)$ only or also on the $r^2\sin\theta$?

Context:I got this from solving a Physics problem involving
$\langle\psi|\hat O|\psi\rangle $ where $\hat O$ contains $\nabla^2$, so 
$$\langle\psi|\hat O|\psi\rangle = \int\psi^*\nabla^2\psi dV$$

Comment: To me, it looks like you are taking the Hessian of $f(.,.,.)$, so it won't affect $r^2sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Right: $r^2 \sin \theta\, dr\, d\theta\, d\phi$ is just the volume form, the equivalent of $dx\, dy\, dz$. The $\nabla^2$ doesn't touch it.

Comment: To make the previous remarks even more explicit: you are evaluating $$\iiint (\nabla^2f)\, dV$$ regardless of the coordinates used. The coordinates only affect how the calculation is carried out, not the concepts themselves. $f$ is a function on points in space. $(r, \theta, \phi)$ is just a way of expressing which point $f$, and $\nabla^2 f$ is being evaluated at. And $dV$ is the volume element. In cartesian coordinates, it is $dxdydz$. In spherical coordinates it is $r^2\sin \theta drd\theta d\phi$. It is not part of $f$, and thus not affected by $\nabla^2$.